# Print integer amount in '*'

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is:

```
ID | Name  | Stars
1  | Harry | 2
2  | Peter | 5
```

I want to create a query which gives the following output:

```
ID | Name  | Stars
1  | Harry | **
2  | Peter | *****
```

How should my query look like? I thought about a loop but this is not possible in postgresql!

Comment: Perhaps, if supported, `repeat('*', stars)`.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Even if you didn't know about the `repeat()` function, you could use `left('**********', stars)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select 
id,
name,
repeat('*', stars)
from table
```